# Como proteger arquivos de imagem e arquivos ini?

Tags: python

Eu estou desenvolvendo um software em *Python* e estou usando arquivos `.ini` e imagens.
Alguém sabe uma forma de proteger esses arquivos contra edição de usuários?

Não quero que o usuário fique trocando as imagens do programa e etc ou alterando o arquivo `.ini` indevidamente.

Pode ser um instalador, um banco de dados.

Comment: Se você colocar um img na maquina do usuário ele vai poder alterar o arquivo. Não tem como bloquear isso, dificultar, até tem, bloquear 100%, nunca.

Comment: Qual sistema operacional?

Comment: Poderia salvar criar uma hash de integridade de todos arquivos e se algum falhar deve existir um backup compactado do ultimo salvamento que deve ser encriptado com uma senha interna que só você tem, não é a mais brilhante ideia, mas deve funcionar bem. Não vou tentar formular nenuma resposta agora, pois é um pouco complexo, assim que possivel, se não tiver nenhuma resposta eu tento formular uma.

Comment: Só uma duvida é Python2 ou 3?

Answer (score 1):

Há varias formas de proteger arquivos, mas com algum esforço sempre conseguirão alterar.

Vou listar alguns meios de proteger(use-os em conjunto para maior eficacia):

1) Verificação de hash: Utilize a hashlib(é uma biblioteca padrão do python, bem fácil de usar) para obter o hash(pode ser md5) dos arquivos que você quer proteger. Se o hash for diferente do da imagem/arquivo original(deixa o hash original em strings dentro do seu código python), você exibe uma mensagem dizendo que o programa foi "corrompido" e exige a reinstalação. No caso do ini, como o hash varia, você terá que armazená-lo em algum outro arquivo.

2) Crie um instalador/executável: py2exe, pyinstaller, cx_freeze... Há varias opções prontas, mas eu sugiro que você faça um pequeno programa instalador utilizando linguagens compiladas(linguagens compiladas são mais difíceis de serem craqueadas, e, como o programa vai servir apenas para iniciar o outro, ele vai ser pequeno). Fazendo seu próprio programa de execução você pode configurar-lo para verificar os arquivos(com hash, como citei no ponto 1) antes de iniciar o programa.

3) Utilize o PIL e o StringIO para deixar a imagem dentro do código python, em forma de string, exemplo:

```
>>>from StringIO import StringIO
>>>from PIL import Image

>>>image_file = StringIO(open("test.jpg",'rb').read())
>>>im = Image.open(image_file)
>>>print im.size, im.mode
```

No seu caso, no lugar do "open("test.jpg",'rb').read()" ficaria a string hard-coded da imagem.
Fonte desse exemplo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22468108/how-to-read-image-from-stringio-into-pil-in-python

4) Banco de dados: Sugiro o SQLAlchemy, é muito fácil de usar e tem todas as ferramentas de um bom gerenciador de banco. Usuários ainda poderão edita-lo, mas já precisarão ter mais conhecimento.

5) Criptografar os arquivos: Funciona de maneira similar ao hash, porém você salva os arquivos criptografados no disco e descriptografa na hora de usar, assim o usuário não saberá se quer o que cada arquivo é.

Todos esses meios supõem que o usuário não tem conhecimentos avançados ou que não terá acesso ao código python, para se proteger de usuários um pouco mais avançados:

1) Use ofuscadores de código: pyminifier, OPY...

2) Crie bibliotecas compartilhadas(".dll" ou ".so") em C/C++ e coloque a verificação de arquivo para ser feita por elas. Além disso, deixe alguns trechos vitais de seu código dentro dessas bibliotecas. Isso requer que você saiba criar bibliotecas compartilhadas em C/C++, não é difícil aprender, mas leva um tempinho. Pode também criar executáveis com a mesma função das bibliotecas que citei, se preferir.

Essas medidas exigem que o usuário tenha conhecimento mais avançado, mas ainda assim, ele conseguirá quebrar se tiver todo o conhecimento.